# Concerning the lifting criterion

Tags: algebraic-topology, covering-spaces, fundamental-groups

(Lifting criterion) Suppose given a covering space $p:(\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0)\to (X,x_0)$ and a map $f:(Y,y_0)\to (X,x_0)$ with $Y$ path-connected and locally path connected. Then a lift $\tilde{f}:(Y,y_0)\to (\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0)$ of $f$ exists iff $f_* (\pi_1 (Y,y_0))\subset p_* (\pi_1 (\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))$.

My question is that: Does this theorem still hold if  $f_* (\pi_1 (Y,y_0))\subset p_* (\pi_1 (\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))$ is replaced by $f_* (\pi_1 (Y,y_0))\cong \leqslant p_* (\pi_1 (\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))$?

Comment: What does $f_* (\pi_1 (Y,y_0))\cong \leqslant p_* (\pi_1 (\tilde{X},\tilde{x}_0))$ mean?

Comment: "isomorphic to a subgroup of" maybe?

Comment: @DavidSheard Yes.

Comment: @M.Ramana Then you should edit your question.

Comment: Can you think of an example where $f_*(\pi_1(Y, y_0))$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0))$ but is not a subgroup of $p_*(\pi_1(\tilde{X}, \tilde{x}_0))$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. Take as an example $Y$ a torus with $\pi_1(Y)=\langle a,b\mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$, and let $\tilde{Y}$ be the cover associated to the subgroup $\langle b\rangle$, ie an infinite cyclinder. Then $\pi_1(\tilde{Y})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ and its image under $p_\ast$ is $\langle b\rangle<\langle a,b\mid aba^{-1}b^{-1}\rangle$.

Now take as your space $X$ the circle which has $\pi_1(X)=\mathbb{Z}$, and let $f$ map this circle to a loop representing the element $a$ in $\pi_1(Y)$. Then $f_\ast(\pi_1(X))$ is $\langle a\rangle$ which is isomorphic to $p_\ast(\pi_1(\tilde{Y}))=\langle b \rangle$, but there is no lift.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice answer.